# How can I apply password to sudo in one line command and execute su root?

Tags: linux, bash

I've created an user named samX with root privilege (have appended "samX    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" in `visudo`).

I'm trying to apply password to `sudo`, then `su root` and execute `whoami` sequentially in one line command. My current command is somewhat as follows, but it complains error: **sudo: su root; whoami: command not found**

```
echo 'CbEYKFKt' | sudo -S 'su root; whoami'
```

In which, 'CbEYKFKt' is the password for user samX.

Is there anyway to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would not pass the password via stdin. Instead I would allow the user to execute the necessary commands via sudo without a password. You can configure that in `/etc/sudoers`

Answer (score 6):

```
echo 'CbEYKFKt' | sudo -S su -c whoami
```

should work - `-c` specifies a command for su whereas in your example you seem to be running a command 'root; whoami' which does not exist - there is no shell to break that up into two separate commands.

Comment: what about this command: `echo 'CbEYKFKt' | sudo -S su -c /etc/init.d/iptables -L -vn`, it complains **su: invalid option -- 'L'**.

Comment: Try quoting the command so so the -L is passed into iptables and not sude ```echo 'CbEYKFKt' | sudo -S su -c "/etc/init.d/iptables -L -vn"```  - I hope 5 years is not too long to wait for this solution.

Answer (score 4):

You should really add a line to your sudoers file such as

```
samX ALL=(ALL:ALL)  NOPASSWD: /sbin/su
```

instead of saving your password in the bash history or any other file. With that, there is no need to enter the password at all.

If you want to perform a different command, add that.

Comment: As you can see, mine version includes your version, thus I don't need to provide root's password, only samX's password is needed.

Comment: @Judking with this line, you don't even need to provide samX's password.

Answer (score 2):

When you login into a shell session via putty or moba where you have stored the login credentials for a non root account, simply add this command to be executed upon login in by putty or moba and it will switch your access to root right away.

`echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S su - && sudo su`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting all commands in one line, you can write codes normally and break it into several lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "CbEYKFKt" | sudo -S echo && sudo -s <<EOF
#put your code here
#All codes will be executed as sudo
EOF
```

Note: passing password like that is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

This Should Work.

```
echo CbEYKFKt | sudo -S; whoami
```