# Why my sudo command in bash cannot be executed via crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sudo

Here's my simple runme.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/echo 'CbEYKFKt' | /usr/bin/sudo -S /bin/su -c "whoami;/etc/init.d/iptables stop"
```

In which, `'CbEYKFKt'` is the password for current user: samX, who has the root privilege (have appended `"samX ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"` in `visudo`). I intend to stop iptables at a specific time in crontab, but nothing happened to iptables service when the time is up. Nevertheless, if I execute `bash runme.sh`, it will works fine.

My crontab is as follows:

```
58 16 * * * /bin/bash /home/data/samX/runme.sh 2>&1 > /home/data/samX/log_cron
```

Nothing will be printed to log_cron file. Is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

**P.S.**
A error is printed after I moved `2>&1` to the end:

**sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo**

Does anyone know what's that mean?

Comment: The order matters: Try `58 16 * * * /bin/bash /home/data/samX/runme.sh > /home/data/samX/log_cron 2>&1`

Comment: As I have told you in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938453/how-can-i-apply-password-to-sudo-in-one-line-command-and-execute-su-root), you should fix your sudoers, but that's just for other readers who want to copy the saved password.

Comment: Why the order will matter? Link to the related official explanation is appreciated :] @martin

Comment: I'm just testing this scenario, once solved, I'll add NOPASSWORD to visudo. Thanks for mention again! @martin

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script) but it has something to do with when file descriptors are opened and so on.

Comment: Just googling the new error returns [that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password)

Comment: Why won't you use root's contab?

Answer (score 1):

Authentification utilities like `sudo` are generally reading the password from the controlling terminal (e.g. thru `/dev/tty`, see [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)), not from standard input. (But you could pass `-S` to `sudo` to ask it to read password on *stdin*)

You could use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) (which is able to deal with terminals), but you could simply configure your `/etc/sudoers` to disable password checking.

For example, you could have a line like

```
%sudo   ALL=NOPASSWD:  ALL
```

in your `/etc/sudoers` file. It would allow any member of the `sudo` group to use `sudo` without typing any password.

This of course *opens a security hole* in your computer. Do that at your own risk.

At last, you could *carefully* wrap your script in a [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executable (write *carefully* such a program in C, then `chmod u+s`  the executable).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting all commands in one line, you can write codes normally and break it into several lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "CbEYKFKt" | sudo -S echo && sudo -s <<EOF
#put your code here
#All codes will be executed as sudo
EOF
```

Comment: yes, first one is to take the password from echo, second one is for EOF,
Note: `-S` and `-s` are different

Comment: I have edited my answer, the previous one was wrong. This one will work.. @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't survive from the latest error regarding `tty` which has been updated in my question. Please have a look, thanks.

Comment: "That's probably because your `/etc/sudoers` file (or any file it includes) has:

`Defaults requiretty`"
from:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password