# sudo su with user name, password and command

Tags: linux, bash, passwords, sudo, su

I am trying to do something like

```
echo 'my_password' | sudo -S su -c some-user ./some_command
```

I have looked at

[How can I apply password to sudo in one line command and execute su root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938453/how-can-i-apply-password-to-sudo-in-one-line-command-and-execute-su-root)

and

[run a sudo command, specifying the password on the same line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275505/run-a-sudo-command-specifying-the-password-on-the-same-line)

But neither of these really answer my question above.

I am still getting the password prompt for my user.

Comment: Why don't you just set sudo up to not prompt for a password for a some-user executing some_command?

Comment: Working with a server where sudo has been setup from another team. So I can't run any commands outside my user. Sucks. Well I am running as root via ansible but this isn't the norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got two answers for you.

The first answer is "don't do it". There is, almost certainly, a better way. You can specify to sudo that certain users can perform certain commands without entering a password. In all likelihood, that is what you want to do.

Having failed to convince you, however, I will let you in on a little secret. `sshpass` works on `sudo`, so:

```
sshpass -p 'my password' sudo -S su -c some-user ./some_command
```

Of course, while there, we can cut the `su` middle man:

```
sshpass -p 'my password' sudo -S -u some-user ./some_command
```

Comment: Using this answer, my system still asks for the password for the currently logged in user

Comment: Using sshpass 1.06 does not have a -S parameter available. This is the most current version on github. What version does this work with?

Comment: `-S` is an argument for sudo, not sshpass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expect. First install the expect rpm then run command look like this:

```
expect -c "spawn sudo /tmp/test.sh; sleep 3; expect -re \"password\"; send \"mypassword\r\n\";set timeout 5;expect -re \"time=\";"
```